# System.PlatformNotSupportedException with MAUI and MySql.Data on .NET 6

Tags: .net, nuget, maui

I'm trying to create a direct connection to a MySQL database with MAUI .NET6 using MySql.Data 8.0.30.

```
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = Constants.connectionString;
        conn.Open();
```

I'm getting a *System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.* exception from .Open(). I know this is pretty self explanatory, but I was under the impression that .NET 6 was completely cross platform, is there a way round this? What should I be looking for in NuGet packages to indicate they are compatible with MAUI if its not .NET 6?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which platform are you getting the exception on?

Comment: @Jason I'm targeting the Android platform

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issues when you built the connection between the MySql sever and your project. The method you chose is right. Then I found a course you can refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNmIdFjXzl4).

In addition, the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html) also provide the method about how to connect to the project.